# deprecated items in Bixby viv

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I am working in the latest version of the Bixby IDE ( Version 6.2.0-rc.5484 ) 
I have downloaded at the example.spaceResorts from git hub (https://github.com/bixbydevelopers/space-resorts)

I compile and get 29 warnings that are all deprecated warnings or this item may be empty.

```
viv.geo
viv.entity
viv.contact
```

one gives the new usage. ie. 'hALgihn' is deprecated. Please use 'halign'

Where do I find out what the viv ones should be now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a member of the Bixby Developer Support team. The good news is that these are warnings and deprecations, so it will not affect the execution of the capsule. Unfortunately, there is not much you can do about the errors (e.g. ERROR_DEPRECATED) coming from the library capsules (viv.geo etc).

We will however be updating our sample capsules to use halign instead of HAlign. More details on halign can be found here: https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/layout-macro-def.content.title-area.halign

Comment: Great thanks, If you haven't already updated I am happy to help out and do it. Just let me know.  Also If I were dong the capsule-imports my self where do I find documentation to tell me what I should be importing/using?

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting deprecated warnings, it's always good to check that you are using the latest version of the library capsules. This will not solve all deprecated warnings but can help.

Here is the list - last updated Nov 18:

```
Library - Capsule Version
viv.business - 4.29.0
viv.contact - 2.5123.0
viv.entity - 3.11.13
viv.geo - 9.6.3
viv.image - 2.8.1
viv.measurement - 2.9.2
viv.money - 2.16.19
viv.navigation - 1.7.17
viv.openHours - 3.18.0
viv.rating - 2.14.4
viv.self - 3.2.24
viv.time - 2.63.9
```

See the docs at: https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/library

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't spotted where to specify the version before.

Comment: so I have explicitly included viv.geo with the latest version and I still get depreciation warnings, do I need to specify the versions for common and core ? Common seems to be pulling in a version of geo.